# Postgresql plpgsql function syntax error

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want to create a function returning a set of records but I get a syntax error. The query is working but when I embed it in a function I get an error. What can be done to return the set?

> Error
>   ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
>   LINE 27:  select id, user_id, project_id, record_date, parselid, pars...
>    ________^
>   ********** Error **********
>       ERROR: syntax error at or near "select"
>       SQL state: 42601
>       Character: 832

**Function code**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getloggeom(
    IN p_lat double precision,
    IN p_lng double precision,
    OUT id integer, 
    OUT user_id bigint, 
    OUT project_id bigint, 
    OUT record_date timestamp without time zone, 
    OUT parselid integer, 
    OUT parselno character varying, 
    OUT adano character varying, 
    OUT ilid integer, 
    OUT ilad character varying, 
    OUT ilceid integer, 
    OUT ilcead character varying, 
    OUT mahallead character varying, 
    OUT mahalleid integer, 
    OUT pafta character varying, 
    OUT nitelik character varying, 
    OUT mevkii character varying, 
    OUT yuzolcum character varying, 
    OUT alan double precision, 
    OUT lat double precision, 
    OUT lng double precision, 
    OUT feature json)
  RETURNS SETOF record AS
$BODY$
    select id, user_id, project_id, record_date, parselid, parselno, adano, ilid, ilad, ilceid, ilcead, mahallead, mahalleid, pafta, nitelik, mevkii, yuzolcum, alan, st_x(st_centroid(st_transform(geom,4326))) as lng, st_y(st_centroid(st_transform(geom,4326))) as lat, (SELECT row_to_json(fc) as data
                     FROM ( SELECT 'FeatureCollection' As type, array_to_json(array_agg(f)) as features
                     FROM ( SELECT 'Feature' as type
                        , ST_AsGeoJSON(st_transform(ST_MakeValid(geom),4326))::json as geometry
                        , row_to_json(( parselid, ilad, ilcead, mahallead, adano, parselno, yuzolcum, st_y(st_centroid(st_transform(geom,4326))), st_x(st_centroid(st_transform(geom,4326))))) As properties
                       FROM log_geom where st_intersects((st_transform(st_setsrid(st_point(p_lng, p_lat), 4326), 500000)),geom ) limit 1)as f )  as fc) as feature  from log_geom where         
        ST_Intersects(
        st_transform(st_setsrid(st_point(p_lng, p_lat), 4326), 500000),geom
    )limit 1;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 1000
  ROWS 1000;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use plpgsql, you must include the `begin / end` [statements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-structure.html) and you must use `RETURN QUERY ...  RETURN;` as per the [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html).

Otherwise you can switch to using [SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html) instead of PLPGSQL and your function would work as is.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getloggeom([...])
  RETURNS SETOF record AS
$BODY$
    [...]
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE SQL
  COST 1000
  ROWS 1000;
```